# Controlling getter and setter for a python's class

Tags: python

Consider the following class :

```
class Token:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d_dict = {}

    def __setattr__(self, s_name, value):
        self.d_dict[s_name] = value

    def __getattr__(self, s_name):
        if s_name in self.d_dict.keys():
            return self.d_dict[s_name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError('No attribute {0} found !'.format(s_name))
```

In my code Token have some other function (like get_all() wich return d_dict, has(s_name) which tell me if my token has a particular attribute).

Anyway, I think their is a flaw in my plan since it don't work : when I create a new instance, python try to call `__setattr__('d_dict', '{}')`.

How can I achieve a similar behaviour (maybe in a more pythonic way ?) without having to write something like Token.set(name, value) and get(name) each I want to set or get an attribute for a token.

Critics about design flaw and/or stupidity welcome :)

Thank !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to special-case d_dict.

Although of course, in the above code, all you do is replicate what any object does with `__dict__` already, so it's pretty pointless. Do I guess correctly if you intended to special case some attributes and actally use methods for those?

In that case, you can use properties.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

Answer (score 3):

The special-casing of `__dict__` works like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__dict__['d_dict'] = {}
```

There is no need to use a new-style class for that.

Comment: I think I'll do that :)

Anyway, I use Python 3.1 so all my class are new style class .

Answer (score 2):

A solution, not very pythonic but works. As Lennart Regebro pointed, you have to use a special case for d_dict.

```
class Token(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Token,self).__setattr__('d_dict', {})

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        return self.a[name]

    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        self.a[name] = value
```

You need to use new style classes.

Answer (score 2):

the problem seems to be in time of evaluation of your code in __init__ method.
You could define __new__ method and initialize d_dict variable there instead of __init__.
Thats a bit hackish but it works, remember though to comment it as after few months it'll be total magic.

```
>>> class  Foo(object):
...     def __new__(cls, *args):
...             my_cls = super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, *args)
...             my_cls.d_dict = {}
...             return my_cls

>>> f = Foo()
>>> id(f.d_dict)
3077948796L
>>> d = Foo()
>>> id(d.d_dict)
3078142804L
```

Word of explanation why I consider that hackish: call to __new__ returns new instance of *class* so then *d_dict* initialised in there is kind of **static**, but it's initialised with new instance of dictionary each time class is "*created*" so everything works as you need.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth remembering that `__getattr__` is only called if the attribute doesn't exist in the object, whereas `__setattr__` is always called.

Answer (score 0):

I think we'll be able to say something about the overall design of your class if you explain its purpose. For example,

```
# This is a class that serves as a dictionary but also has user-defined methods
class mydict(dict): pass

# This is a class that allows setting x.attr = value or getting x.attr:
class mysetget: pass

# This is a class that allows setting x.attr = value or getting x.attr:
class mygetsethas: 
    def has(self, key):
        return key in self.__dict__

x = mygetsethas()
x.a = 5
print(x.has('a'), x.a)
```

I think the last class is closest to what you meant, and I also like to play with syntax and get lots of joy from it, but unfortunately this is not a good thing. Reasons why it's not advisable to use object attributes to re-implement dictionary: you can't use `x.3`, you conflict with `x.has()`, you have to put quotes in `has('a')` and many more.

Comment: My goal is to provide a container that allow me to give it any arbitrary attribute (I don't in advance how many nor their name), eg : 
myClassInstance.name1 = value1
myClassInstance.name2 = value2

With the appropriate call, I want to retrieve a dictionary that will contain my attributes' name and value under the following form :
{'name1': value1, 'name2': value2}

valueX can be any python's or custom's type.

Comment: Then your best best is the second one, `class mysetget: pass`. You'll be able to set attributes and then retrieve them with 'x.__dict__`.